# split string using re and add integers in python

Tags: python, regex

I have following string

> '100000|^104,500|^^0^0^0^0^0^0^0|^^^^^^^^^412824|103000|103000|103000|103000^^'

How to sum last 5 integers after `|^^^^^^^^^` till `^^` separated by `|`.

I tried `re.split('[|^^^^^^^^^]', string)` but it splits using `|^` delimiter and returns list.

Comment: `re.split('^^^^^^^^^', string)`?

Comment: When you say sum, you expect an integer number or concatenation of strings ?

Comment: Well then, what's the desired output?

Comment: `sum(map(int, s.split('|^^^^^^^^^')[1].split('^^')[0].split('|')))` >>> `824824` ?

Comment: There this aweful solution : `last_digits_sum = sum(map(int, a.split('^^^^^^^^^')[-1].split('^^')[0].split('|')))` output : `824824` that will give tou the sum of the last digits. But does it generalize well to your case ?

Comment: it will work, but I'm expecting to do this using regex

Comment: Thanks, guys for your responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
string = '100000|^104,500|^^0^0^0^0^0^0^0|^^^^^^^^^412824|103000|103000|103000|103000^^'    
answer = sum(map(int, re.search(r'\^{9}(.+)\^\^', string).group(1).split('|')))
```

answer:

```
824824
```

Comment: what is there is float value in string `'100000|^104,500|^^0^0^0^0^0^0^0|^^^^^^^^^769729.878108065|0|0|0|0^^'`

Comment: @parvez simply replace `int` with `float`

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.search` #Lookbehind & Lookahead

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = '100000|^104,500|^^0^0^0^0^0^0^0|^^^^^^^^^412824|103000|103000|103000|103000^^'
d = re.search(r"(?<=\^{9}).*?(?=\^{2})", s)
if d:
    print( sum(map(int, d.group().split("|"))) )
```

**Output:**

```
824824
```

Comment: what is there is float value in string `'100000|^104,500|^^0^0^0^0^0^0^0|^^^^^^^^^769729.878108065|0|0|0|0^^'`

Comment: Then you can use `print( sum(map(float, d.group().split("|"))) )`

Answer (score 1):

Those characters are special in regular expressions and need to be escaped. Try with this:

```
import re

s = '100000|^104,500|^^0^0^0^0^0^0^0|^^^^^^^^^412824|103000|103000|103000|103000^^'
nums = re.split(r'\|\^{9}', s)[1]
# Find all integers and sum
total = sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', nums)))
print(total)
```

Output:

```
824824
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this (but without re library )

```
a='100000|^104,500|^^0^0^0^0^0^0^0|^^^^^^^^^412824|103000|103000|103000|103000^^'
a=a.split('^'*9)
a=(a[1]).replace('^^','')
a=a.split('|')
s = 0
for i in a:
    s += int(i)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

A fully-regex solution could use this regex:

`.+\|\^{9}|[\^\|]+`

You can split using this regex. The resulting array will contain some empty elements, however, you can easily check for them while adding.

Answer (score 0):

with findall() and negative lookahead:

```
sum( int(i) for i in re.findall(r"(?!.*\^{9})\d+",s))
```